# D3.js Focus + brushing

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to understand how it is possible to put the focus on the d3.js. I searched several answers on Stackoverflow and Observable and was unable to put the data in the time series without overlapping them on the chart when using the focus. Could anyone suggest a possible solution?
I really like how the data is presented with a beginning and an end in this chart.

This plnkr is working without the focus:

[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/8LIpOBbP40jEInFr?preview)

I tried to add this:

```
var focus = c.svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 15 + "," + 0 + ")");

focus.append("path.player")
     .datum(players, 'path.player')
     .attr("cliPath", "url(#clip)")
     .attr("class", "path.player")
     .attr("d", line);

focus.append("g")
     .attr("class", "x axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + 10 + "," + 0 + ")")
     .call(c.xAxis);
      
focus.append("g")
     .attr("class", "y axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + 10 + "," + 10 + ")")
     .call(c.yAxis);
```

And changed to this:

```
function brushed() {
    c.x.domain(brush.empty() ? v.x.domain() : brush.extent());
focus.dataAppend(players, 'path.player')
    .attr('d', ƒ('years', line));
focus.selectAll( "path.player").transition()
    .attr('d', ƒ('years', line));
  focus.selectAll(".x.axis").transition().call(c.xAxis).attr("transform", "translate(" + 10 + "," + 40 + ")");
}
```

The result still seems to overlap the line on the chart. Something is missing and I don't know what it is.

Comment: "The result still seems to overlap the line on the chart" : Do you mean the plotted data overlaps the y axis when zooming in? If so, you'll need to use a clipping path to only draw the data within the plot area, [eg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48486454/7106086).

Comment: Exactly, when zooming in, the line overlaps. I tried several times to understand how the "brushed" function works. I'm listening to your comment on using "clipping path" ..

Comment: I tried this..'focus.append("path.player")
     .datum(players, 'path.player')
     .attr("cliPath", "url(#clip)")
     .attr("class", "path.player")
  .call(drawLines(c), drawLines(v))


function brushed() {
  c.x.domain(brush.empty() ? v.x.domain() : brush.extent());
  c.svg.select(".x.axis").transition().call(c.xAxis);
  focus.selectAll("path.player").call(drawLines(c), drawLines(v))

}'

Comment: I really need help, any suggestion